# Join two tables if a.var contains a number

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to join two tables by a.class = b.class but only if the value in a.class has a number someplace in it (abc4dfg). Otherwise I only want the output of ncm.tbla and no join to the other table, is this possible?

```
SELECT a.grid, a.state, a.class,
    IF(a.class REGEXP '[0-9]', b.cnty)
  FROM ncm.tbla a
  LEFT JOIN fcc.tblb b
         ON (a.class LIKE '%ncmo%'
        AND a.class = b.class)
```

Comment: "Otherwise I only want the output of ncm.tbla and no join to the other table, is this possible?" No you can't write conditional join's in like that in SQL.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, I would like think adding something like this to your ON clause would work:

```
SELECT a.grid, a.state, a.class, b.cnty
FROM ncm.tbla a
LEFT JOIN fcc.tblb b 
    ON (a.class = b.class AND a.class LIKE '%[0-9]%')
```

Comment: Won't work.. `%[0-9]%` will literally search for the pattern `[0-9]` within the column a.class.

Comment: I think this is close. The problem is that the filter;   AND a.class LIKE '%ncmo%'   does not get applied and all of the values in ncm.tbla are returned.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the [0-9] is the way to go, it does not get treated like a regular expression, it is looking for any character, then a character that is between 0-9 and then any characters after.  I'm a little confused on what exact statements you want to filter on.  I also think that you could potentially move 1 or 2 from the ON clause to a where clause.

Comment: @user2780362 This is exactly what I was using REGEXP '[0-9]' not LIKE. Thank you.